# I am using ADMINLTE2 gem in rails 4. sometimes 'sidebar view partial' does not load contents when I refresh the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am rendering this partial in adminlte.html.erb file but it is not loading properly. I tried to put this code inside the admin file itself which is rendering this partial but it is still not loading properly.I also checked in other browsers.When I inspect the element,the sidebar suddenly loads by itself.

```
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
      <div class="user-panel">
        <div class="pull-left image">
        <%= image_tag("user2-160x160.jpg", class: 'img-circle')%>
        <!-- <img src="images/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />-->
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left info">
          <p>abcd</p>

          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- search form -->
      <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control"   placeholder="Search..."/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type='submit' name='search' id='search-btn' class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- /.search form -->
      <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
      <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
  <!--Dashboard--> 
        <li class="active treeview">
          <a href="/">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> <i class="fa fa-circle-o pull-right"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
  <!-- Dashboard END -->


  <!--USER--> 
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Manage User</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="<%= new_user_path %>" ><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Create User</a></li>
            <li><a href="/users"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> List User</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
  <!-- USER END -->

  <!--MY_PROJECT -->
      <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>
            <span>My Project</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="pages/layout/top-nav.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Active</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/layout/boxed.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Completed</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/layout/fixed.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Hold</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
  <!--END MYPROJECT-->

  <!--FOLLOW UPS -->
      <li>
          <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <span>Followups</span>
            <small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>
          </a>
        </li>
  <!--END FOLLOW UPS -->

  <!--FOLLOW UPS -->
      <li>
          <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html">
            <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> <span>Manage RMs</span>
          </a>
        </li>
  <!--END FOLLOW UPS -->

  <!-- CALLS -->

        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="call_records/">
            <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>
            <span>Calls</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="/call_records?status=DEFAULT"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Open</a></li>
            <li><a href="/call_records/"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> All</a></li>
            <li><a href="/call_records?status=REJECTED"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Rejected</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

  <!--END  CALLS -->

  <!-- CONTACTS -->

        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-file-audio-o"></i>
            <span>Contacts</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="pages/layout/top-nav.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> +New Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/layout/boxed.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Assigned</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/layout/fixed.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Open</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/layout/collapsed-sidebar.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> All</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/layout/collapsed-sidebar.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Rejected</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

  <!--END  CONTACTS -->

  <!-- ACTIONS -->

        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
            <span>Actions</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="pages/layout/top-nav.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Top Navigation</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/layout/boxed.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Boxed</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/layout/fixed.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Fixed</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/layout/collapsed-sidebar.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Collapsed Sidebar</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

  <!--END  ACTIONS -->
      </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>
```

I'm rendering this partial like

```
<html>
    <body>
        <%= render partial: 'layouts/admin_lte_2_sidebar' %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me out to solve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using slimscroll jquery plugin.I found this was the reason it was not loading properly but i need that plugin in my application.Can anybody help me please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the height value in slimScrollDiv

```
<div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 480px;">
```

What you can do from here on is to modify your css into

```
.slimScrollDiv{height: auto !important;}
```

This will not limit the height of the div

Comment: @user191990 Sure, no problem. Do accept my answer :)